# Ms Access FollowHyperlink Ebay login

Tags: html

The plan is to connect to my Ebay account, open Revise listing page and add a new SKU# with [Custom Label], then close the page.  Using FollowHyperlink `https://bulksell.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SingleList&sellingMode=ReviseItem&&lineId=130830715244&guest=1`

I can't get past the Ebay sign in.  If i'm going about it wrong, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank You June7!  I was able to login to my revise listing page.  I keep getting a runtime 91 error, Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: at oBrowser.Document.all.Item("subAcctLoginName").Value = "username"    Also what code is used navigate to and/or select a value to change after the code you provided?  Thank You Again!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think FollowHyperlink will be useful. Here is example VBA code that opens a website login page and passes username and password to the page. Have to know names of the input boxes on the page.

```
'open ASTM/AASHTO test standards website and pass agency username/password to the web page
    Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    oBrowser.Silent = True
    oBrowser.Navigate "https://login.ihserc.com/login/erc?"
    oBrowser.Visible = True
    Do
        'Wait till the Browser is loaded
    Loop Until oBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    oBrowser.Document.all.Item("subAcctLoginName").Value = "username"
    oBrowser.Document.all.Item("subAcctPassword").Value = "password"
    oBrowser.Document.all.Item("Submit").Click
```

Tried to adapt for EBay but there is a lot of source code to wade through to find names of the boxes, assuming they have distinct names. I had to use MS Edge to get the source code view to open. If you want to utilize EBay API, search web. Here is one https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/11447/accessing-ebay-api-using-vba-in-excel.html.